# javascript - match string against the array of regular expressions

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression

Is there a way in JavaScript to get Boolean value for a match of the string against the array of regular expressions?

The example would be (where the 'if' statement is representing what I'm trying to achieve):

```
var thisExpressions = [ '/something/', '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/'];
var thisString = 'else';

if (matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions)) {

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a match against all expressions (AND), or any of the expressions (OR)?

Comment: With jquery you can use jQuery.inArray();

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9nyhh/1/

```
var thisExpressions = [/something/, /something_else/, /and_something_else/];
var thisExpressions2 = [/else/, /something_else/, /and_something_else/];
var thisString = 'else';

function matchInArray(string, expressions) {

    var len = expressions.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (string.match(expressions[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

};

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions));
    console.log(matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions2));
}, 200)​
```

Comment: Why not strip the res variable out entirely, return true in your if statement and return false at the end. Then it will quit on finding the first match.

Comment: Also i'd use expressions[i].test(string) rather than string.match()

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: What about let's say I wanted the index of the value that was matched?

Answer (score 139):

Using a more functional approach, you can implement the match with a one-liner using an [array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

ECMAScript 6:

```
const regexList = [/apple/, /pear/];
const text = "banana pear";
const isMatch = regexList.some(rx => rx.test(text));
```

ECMAScript 5:

```
var regexList = [/apple/, /pear/];
var text = "banana pear";
var isMatch = regexList.some(function(rx) { return rx.test(text); });
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning the `filter` method for `Array`s, which is often useful and is used in the same way.

Comment: Also, check out `.every` if you want it to match all in the array vs `.some` which returns true if it matches any in the array.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for modern JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [.test()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) which returns a boolean value when is find what your looking for in another string:

```
var thisExpressions = [ '/something/', '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/'];
var thisString = new RegExp('\\b' + 'else' + '\\b', 'i');
var FoundIt = thisString.test(thisExpressions);  
if (FoundIt) { /* DO STUFF */ }
```

Comment: RegExp.prototype.test() cannot be used with an Array. It takes a string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: @gdibble it will work, because `test` it calls `toString` on the supplied argument, which, for array, will `join()`. Probably not advisable though!

Comment: Example: `/monkey/.test({  toString : () => "monkey" }) // true`

Comment: @Likwid_T - what does '\\b' mean ? I know that 'i' means case insensitive, but I could not find online what \\b means. Also, why do you have it twice?

Comment: @WickyNilliams fair enough my friend ;)

Comment: @GK79 a `\b` is a word-boundary - such that you could match `/\broller\b/` in just the word 'roller' but it would not match 'rollercoaster', however if you took off the trailing `\b` then it would match the first part of 'rollercoaster'

Answer (score 2):

Consider breaking this problem up into two pieces:

1. `filter` out the items that `match` the given regular expression
2. determine if that filtered list has `0` matches in it

```js
const sampleStringData = ["frog", "pig", "tiger"];

const matches = sampleStringData.filter((animal) => /any.regex.here/.test(animal));

if (matches.length === 0) {
  console.log("No matches");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Andersh's solution will not work if you have global flags.** 
A true return will toggle on and off on future identical tests.

```
regexArray.some( rx => rx.test( "a" ))    // true
regexArray.some( rx => rx.test( "a" ))    // false
regexArray.some( rx => rx.test( "a" ))    // true
```

(read why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results))
This works and is also a one-liner:

```
const isMatch = regexList.map( rx => rx.source).includes( string )
```

`.source` returns the text string of the RegExp pattern.
`.map` returns an array of these strings.
`.includes` returns if the string is in the array
(if you need the index, use `.indexOf`)
Alternatively:

```js
function isInsideArray( string, regexArray ){
  return regexArray.map( regex => regex.source).includes( string )
}

function isInsideArray_Andersh( string, regexArray ){
  return regexArray.some( rx => rx.test( string )) 
}

    
const list_rx = [ /apple/g, /pear/g, /banana/g ],
      string  = "pear"

console.log( isInsideArray( string, list_rx ))
console.log( 'Andersh:', isInsideArray_Andersh( string, list_rx ))
console.log( 'Andersh (same test):', isInsideArray_Andersh( string, list_rx ))
```

Answer (score 1):

look this way...

```
function matchInArray(stringSearch, arrayExpressions){
    var position = String(arrayExpressions).search(stringSearch);
    var result = (position > -1) ? true : false
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all regular expressions into single one. This way the string is
scanned only once. Even with a sligthly more complex regular expression.

```
var thisExpressions = [ /something/, /something_else/, /and_something_else/];
var thisString = 'else';


function matchInArray(str, expr) {
    var fullExpr = new RegExp(expr
        .map(x=>x.source) // Just if you need to provide RegExp instances instead of strings or ...
        // .map(x=>x.substring(1, x.length -2)  // ...if you need to provide strings enclosed by "/" like in original question.
        .join("|")
    )
    return str.match(fullExpr);

};


if (matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions)) {
    console.log ("Match!!");
}
```

In fact, even with this approach, if you need check the same expression set
against multiple strings, this is a few suboptimal because you are building
(and compiling) the same regular expression each time the function is called.

Better approach would be to use a function builder like this:

```
var thisExpressions = [ /something/, /something_else/, /and_something_else/];
var thisString = 'else';

function matchInArray_builder(expr) {
    var fullExpr = new RegExp(expr
        .map(x=>x.source) // Just if you need to provide RegExp instances instead of strings or ...
        // .map(x=>x.substring(1, x.length -2)  // ...if you need to provide strings enclosed by "/" like in original question.
        .join("|")
    )   

    return function (str) {
        return str.match(fullExpr);

    };
};  

var matchInArray = matchInArray_builder(thisExpressions);

if (matchInArray(thisString)) {
    console.log ("Match!!");
}
```

Comment: What about let's say I wanted the index of the value that was matched?

Comment: `matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions).index`

Comment: Would it be going after the `var matchInArray = matchInArray_builder(thisExpressions);`? like this: `var matchInArray = matchInArray_builder(thisExpressions); var index = matchInArray(thisString, thisExpressions).index`?

Comment: No. I put an extra parameter by mistake. `matchInArray()` function returns the outcome of `String.match()`. Hence, in fact the "if" condition isn't a boolean value but a complete structure (which evaluates to true) reporting the matched substring and its position…

Comment: ahhhhh... i misread your return statement within the function :)

Comment: But it is essential. The function would return undefined (falsy) unconditionally otherwise ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let expressions = [ '/something/', '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/'];

let str = 'else';
```

here will be the check for following expressions:

```
if( expressions.find(expression => expression.includes(str) ) ) {

}
```

using Array .find() method to traverse array and .include to check substring

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `String.match()`, in case your array contains both match strings and regular expressions, you can do

```
let str = "The quick brown fox";
let matches = ["fox", "The.*fox", /the.*fox/i];
let strInMatches = matches.some(match => str.match(match));
console.log(strInMatches);
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the first match, or `undefined` if no regex matches.

```
function matchAny(str, regExps) {
  for (const regex of regExps) {
    const match = str.match(regex)
    if (match) {
      return match
    }
  }
}
```

This returns `true` if at least 1 regex matches, or `false` if no regex matches.

```
function matchSome(str, regExps) {
  for (const regex of regExps) {
    const exists = regex.test(str)
    if (exists) {
      return exists
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

So we make a function that takes in a literal string, and the array we want to look through. it returns a new array with the matches found. We create a new regexp object inside this function and then execute a String.search on each element element in the array. If found, it pushes the string into a new array and returns.

```
// literal_string: a regex search, like /thisword/ig
// target_arr: the array you want to search /thisword/ig for.

function arr_grep(literal_string, target_arr) {
  var match_bin = [];
  // o_regex: a new regex object.
  var o_regex = new RegExp(literal_string);
  for (var i = 0; i < target_arr.length; i++) {
    //loop through array. regex search each element.
    var test = String(target_arr[i]).search(o_regex);
    if (test > -1) {
    // if found push the element@index into our matchbin.
    match_bin.push(target_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return match_bin;
}

// arr_grep(/.*this_word.*/ig, someArray)
```

Comment: this solution is too complicated considering the simplicity of the problem