# How to check if url with parameter match with the filename in ignore array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Am creating a web page that used ajax to load content and `localCache` technique to store loaded page for later use. Everything seems to work well except that i will like to ignore some page which i have also implemented a simple method to do that but the problem is when the URL is full `https://example.com/view_item.php` it won't ignore it but `view_item.php` it will ignore. and also some page that has url parameter it won't ignore it too `view_item.php?item=123`, `view_item.php?item=123&title=abc` or `https://example.com/view_item.php?item=123 etc` because i can't add those url in ignore array as it do change. I suggest that this can be archived using `regex` but am not show how.

```
var localCache = {
    data: {},
    remove: function (url) {
        delete localCache.data[url];
    },
    exist: function (url) {
        return localCache.data.hasOwnProperty(url) && localCache.data[url] !== null;
    },
    get: function (url) {
         console.debug('fatching data from URL ', url);
        return localCache.data[url];
    },
    set: function (url, check, cachedData, callback) {
         if(this.ignore(check)){
            console.debug('Need To Ignore URL ', check);
        }else{
            localCache.remove(url);
            localCache.data[url] = cachedData;
             console.debug('caching data from URL ', url);
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) callback(cachedData);
        }
    },
    ignore: function(url){
      var Arrays = [
          'cart.php',
          'favorites.php',
          'view_item.php'
      ];
      return ($.inArray( url, Arrays ) !== -1);
    }
};
```

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152650/javascript-match-regular-expression-against-the-array-of-items

Comment: Just use what @VelimirTchatchevsky mentioned by replacing the usage of `$.inArray` with the code in the link. You will also need to replace the array contents. E.g.: instead of `'cart.php'` something like `/.*cart.php.*/`. Regardless of that, controlling a "blacklist" of non-cacheable resources seems to be a code smell. Your server should use the proper headers and the requesting code should be able to read response headers and act accordingly

Comment: @GriffoGoes what am actually trying to do is to minimize the amount of request am sending to server. I want to abort the ajax request from client side once the file is in ignore list or use the old data, if i check for ignore in server side then no much need for my cache

Comment: @GriffoGoes please can you explain to me why `/.*cart.php.*/` not this `/cart.php/`, i want to know the difference and how it can benefit me

Comment: @Peter Oops, no need for `.*`. It means to match any character (`.`) any number of times (`*` matches 0 to infinity). But without it will still works as it will match something in the middle. And regarding my suggestion, here's a link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control . The idea is to inform the browser which url is "cacheable" and which is not.