# Regex to accept only 7 types of special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my react-native application, I have a requirement to accept 7 types of special characters in a string. It could be all 7, few of them or none of them.

Special characters are `(),@'/-`

so the accepted string will be like following.

1. `ABcd()ef,/'-@sdf` => accepting all 7
2. `ABcd(),` => accepting few of 7
3. `ABcddfg` => accepting none of 7

How should I write this regex in java script?

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152699/3305456

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean

https://regex101.com/r/Vt9wmF/1

```
/[\w\(\),@'\/-]/g
```