# Check if an item of an array is in a string using Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, es6-promise

I need some simple javascript code for a Vue application that will take a string split it into an array and check if any value is in a different string.

I have

```
              let AffiliationString = " This person goes to Stony Brook"

              let affiliation = "Stony Brook OR Stony Brook University OR The University of Washington"
              let affiliations = affiliation.toLowerCase().split(" or ");
              affiliation = affiliations.join(",");
               let regexList = [ affiliation ];

               let isMatch = regexList.some(rx => rx.test(AffiliationString));
```

I want to see if any item in the array is in the "AffiliationString" string

When I do this I get the following error

```
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: rx.test is not a function
```

I have seen many samples on StackOverflow of checking the array if a value is there but not the other way around.
I'm trying to use
               [javascript - match regular expression against the array of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152650/javascript-match-regular-expression-against-the-array-of-items)

I'm doing this in a Vue project with

```
         "eslint": "6.7.2",
```

do I need to redo it as a loop for each value in the array?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually making `RegExp`'s out of your `affiliation` string, which is why `rx.test` is not a function. You can make a `RegExp` which will match against all the affiliation string pieces at once, by separating them with `|`. We wrap each element in the regex in `\b` so that (for example) `Brook` doesn't match `Brooktown`. Adding the `i` flag to the `RegExp` makes it case-insensitive:

```js
let AffiliationString = " This person goes to Stony Brook"
let affiliation = "Stony Brook OR Stony Brook University OR The University of Washington"
let regex = new RegExp('\\b' + affiliation.split(/\s+or\s+/i).join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b', 'i')
let isMatch = regex.test(AffiliationString)
console.log(isMatch)
```